# al llamar al producto y que me muestre la imagen

Tags: imagen, asp

Al poner el código no me lee para que después me muestre una imagen

y este es el código que uso para que me muestre la imagen:

```
<img src= <%# "img/" Response.rediect( Session(" imagen ") ) %> />
```

Comment: ¿`rediec` o `redirect`? Además, ¿cuál es el problema en cuestión? Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Comment: disculpe me comí una letra   mi problema es que al mandar un producto para ver como precio  y pesificaciones  no me aparece  la imagen del producto que para ver  solo me muestra nombre precio y no la imagen